# Large JSON object in browser client

Tags: javascript, json, performance, browser

I have a large JSON object of about 8 MB from a server stored in a browser client.  If I cut down the name of variables that are duplicated in these lists will that give a performance boost at all when manipulating the lists and updating the objects?

```
    { "VenueLocationID" : 12 }

    { "vid" : 12 }
```

Comment: it will just make the file size smaller, nothing more than that.

Comment: So a large JSON object in the dom per se, wouldnt get a performance benefit from making the property names smaller, etc when manipulating it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719887/variable-name-length-vs-performance

Comment: Easy way to test it yourself. https://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you're transferring 8MB of data from server to client, probably.  However, there are better ways to improve performance.  If your JSON is coming through an HTTP response, activating gzip compression could net even better performance without reducing readability.

The best way to tune performance is to profile the application -- find out where the bottlenecks are, then address them.  Profilers can sometimes find things that I never thought would be issues.

Another thing to look at is how the JSON is being built.  I've helped some systems out by stream-parsing.  Instead of serializing (stringifying) one huge array, I serialized each element [and wrote it to a response stream,] surrounded by the typical delimiters (`'['`, `']'`, and `','`).

Comment: I did that for the actual download, but you guys dont understand after the browser unzips it, its still 8MB in the browser because its the same JSON.

Comment: Actually, this gal understands completely.  I suggested the above techniques, because I/O (network, disk) tends to be a bigger bottleneck than RAM.  If your client can't fit the object in memory without going to virtual RAM (swap), then [it is also an I/O issue.]

Comment: We havent had issues with this large object, but I am asking do you get a benefit with having a smaller footprint because of cutting down on naming properties, etc.  If not, "IN THE BROWSER", not the http request, which was already done.

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered, sorry to waste your time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719887/variable-name-length-vs-performance

Comment: Can you answer this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266089/should-i-destroy-json-object-when-navigating-to-different-page-on-spa

Comment: The other answer to which you referred is talking about variables, not properties.  [Objects may have different behaviors in RAM, because the interpreter has to keep track of their names as strings.]

Comment: Well the property stores an object.